# Eclipse IDE Some random words

Tags: java, eclipse

[my project name is not in English how do I revert it back to english](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmP0Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird font(s) installed on your system that don't play nicely with Eclipse. You can change your Eclipse theme to Classic to avoid this issue.

```
Windows Menu > Preferences > General > Appearance > Theme
```